# ActiveAdmin and additional custom CSS files

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Where can i put custom css files to customize ActiveAdmin CSS?

I see in active_admin.rb there is the following line:

```
config.register_stylesheet 'active_admin.css'
```

but i can't understand where the file has to go. 
All i want to do is add some extra custom styles to AA's default ones

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Lets say I have 2 css files, highlight.css and select2.css

In `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`, I would add it like this:

```
config.register_stylesheet 'highlight.min.css'
config.register_stylesheet 'select2.css'
```

**Note:**

*highlight.css* and *select2.css* should be inside/under `app/assets/stylesheets`

Comment: ok it actually worked but i realized that you cannot name those file: active_admin.css otherwise it will override the whole thing!

Comment: Oh. I didnt knew that.

Comment: Or you can just `@import` those files inside `active_admin.css`

Comment: This is deprecated: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/5419

Answer (score 0):

> To keep separate directory for admin style-sheet.

I am using `gem 'activeadmin'` in an application.
I wanted to use my own style-sheet which stored in separate directory, here is how I archive that-

1. Created new directory as **`admin`** inside style-sheet .
   Ex. **`app/assets/stylesheets/admin`**
2. Opened `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`.
3. Looked for ***register_stylesheet*** and found commented line as-

   `# config.register_stylesheet 'my_stylesheet.css'`
4. Modified this line with-

   `config.register_stylesheet 'admin/active_style.css'`
5. Restart rails server and found desired result.

Hope will work for you!